# Setting up GST invoice application report differs for item wise sales against total sales

Tags: sql, rounding, invoice, tax

We have set up GST application where I am getting difference between reports like monthly item wise sales report against monthly total sales report.

Please suggest me any changes I need to make for following rules:

We have 3 tables 
A. Order master - single line for every order is stored with summarized values
B. Order product details - Each line item stored with respective qty, price etc.
C. Order tax details - line item wise tax details having separate row for CGST, SGST etc.

Here is how I am storing the data:

1. Tax is applicable on every line item [To generate final invoice all items in order group, we create some of all line items and storing value in Order Master.]
2. We are rounding 2 decimal value for 3 precision [eg. 4.657 = 4.66, 4.643 = 4.64] as per GST council
3. Rounding value is stored in Order Master table
4. For discount there are 2 cases

   - Percent based discount - Let's say if discount is 10% then from every individual line item 10% discount gets deducted than tax will be applicable for each line item
   - Flat discount - Let's say for 1000/- Rs order somebody wants to give 80/- Rs. discount than from each line item 8% is deducted and than tax will be applied, off course customer may not pay exact 920/- Rs. amount due to reversal of tax amount.

Now when I am generating following reports:

1. Monthly item wise sales report [Product wise sales report]
2. Monthly total sales report [Total sales]
3. Monthly payment type wise report [Bank, Cheque, Cash]

I am getting difference due to rounding of values. Can anyone suggest me which is the best way to set up **rounding formula and up to which decimal point should I go to round the values.**

I am using SQL server as backend and .net as front end technology.

Comment: Use more decimal places (at least two more) and round down to two in the last step.

Comment: So need to store values of line items with 4 decimal. like 4.6789 and in last do I need to do round off?

Comment: The rounding seems to be something that your application demands.  I am just suggesting a way to fix your problem in most cases.